# Entity framework to Entity framework core in .Net 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to convert class library project which has Entity model (.edmx) and context.CS classes, built with .net framework 4 to a class library project with entity framework core in .Net6. Could anyone give your inputs on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to decide you want to use code first approach or database first approach.

For reference, you can visit microsoft website :
[Code First to an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database), and [Database First EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first)

After decide, copy your model classes and start working with new project with existing database.